# How to access current memory warning level in DidReceiveMemoryWarning in Monotouch 6.2 (Xamarin.iOS)?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, didreceivememorywarning

I would like to know how one can programmatically access the current memory warning level in DidReceiveMemoryWarning, in Monotouch 6.2 (now called Xamarin.iOS), working with iOS6.

Also, how many memory warning levels are there?

The reason for this is that I would like to see the severity of the warning and accordingly do the needful in releasing memory resources.

If there is a way to get this using Objective C, I can probably work out the equivalent way in Monotouch. I did not find anything about this in the Monotouch documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be only one warning, or an infinite amount.

If you get a warning and don't free anything, your app will most likely be killed before you get another one. If you do free memory, and later use it again, you might get another warning, and this may go on indefinitely.

When you get a memory warning you should just free as much memory as you can, there is no way to know how much iOS actually needs, so just err on the side of caution and clean up as much as you can.